# Intersection Turning Movement counts

Tags: counter, datalogger, matching

Civil Traffic Engineers have a perpetual data gathering problem. They need intersection turning movement counts to do their studies. This has historically been a manual task. Someone sits by the intersection all day long and counts number of vehicles turning in each direction  and only recently has one company started using machine vision to automate this process (Miovision). The other method is to use License plate recognition on the 4 legs of the intersection and see which vehicles turned from where. I was wondering if there are any other ideas that can be used to count turning movements more easily. The biggest challenge is identifying vehicles accurately as they go through the intersections. Is it possible to measure the temperature or sound profile of a vehicle before it enters the intersection and after it leaves the intersection and match up these values to see which way it turned?

Comment: It would be "easy enough" to lay down a sensor grid in the intersection that detected vehicles as they moved over each sensor. A continuous map of movements would allow most vehicles to be correctly tracked.The sensors could be standalone battery powered and anchored to the roadway "wuitably" or wire connected with wires in eg tape form so it could be tuck down well enough to resists "perturbing forces" (most of the time :-)).  If the local hoons find out that  a locked up wheels drift through the intersection takes out all your sensors then all bets are off. Otherwise probably workable.

Comment: Short range inductive proximity sensors and a radio or IR tx per each could probably be cheap, low profile and robust enough

Comment: @Russell Your comments seem like an answer to the question, why not post as such?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that vehicle plate, type, etc. does not need to be recorded, Infrared sensors can be installed at turns to detect the vehicle.

Two sensors on each turn are needed to avoid any false counts.

This may help [How to make a digital object counter using, infrared sensor](http://www.buildcircuit.com/object-counter/)

Comment: I think Traffic is trying to count vehicles that are turning only. The problem with standard counting methods is that they will also count vehicles that are going straight. For example, consider an eastbound right-hand lane that accepts vehicles coming from the west as well as right-turns coming from the south. How would you differentiate between these origins?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it would be possible to identify turn movements with just passive sound sensors. It might work with an array of sensors but I think it would still be difficult getting good enough resolution to tell which vehicle is which.

Infrared cameras can be used instead of video. They have similar performance, with some advantages and disadvantages: things like variation in light level don't affect tracking (so they probably wouldn't have as much trouble at night as regular video cameras) but infrared cameras are typically more expensive and lower-framerate and resolution.

My feeling is that regular old video is the most effective sensor - the difficulty is mostly in processing the video correctly. Mounting position can also have a major impact on the effectiveness of video tracking.

Full disclosure - I'm a developer for this system:
www.traffic-camera.com

Answer (score 1):

I read of a system (but can't remember where - it might be Elektor magazine) where pedestrian routes trough a city were being plotted using **Bluetooth** monitors strapped to lamp posts. I suspect that this relied on the relatively slow speed of pedestrians to give time for the Bluetooth Inquiry to complete. It may not work quickly enough for the junction application.

If it did work at all and a scanner was placed at each entrance and exit of the junction it should be possible to match up the vehicles if two successful scans were obtained. The Bluetooth system would, in time, give the ratios of cars taking each route. This information when combined with standard traffic counters should give a reasonably accurate count.

An article, [Bluetooth Tracking without Discoverability](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/www/publications/public/sjeh3/55610120.pdf) 
by 
Simon Hay and Robert Harle, 
University of Cambridge Computer Laboratory,
gives good detail on the feasibility of such a system in an indoor situation.

I don't know enough about Bluetooth connectivity but offer this as an interesting approach to the problem

See also [How long does it take to scan for Bluetooth devices in range of an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837644/how-long-does-it-take-to-scan-for-bluetooth-devices-in-range-of-an-iphone) on EE.SE.